# Getting an Exception when tried to generate Java SOAP JAX-WS web service from WSDL in JDeveloper

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, jdeveloper

When I am trying to generate Java Soap-web-service from wsdl in Jdeveloper tool Below is the exception I am getting. Could you please any one suggest me the solution for below error :

Here is the Error which i got in console  :

```
Jan 11, 2017 12:37:59 PM oracle.security.jps.util.JpsUtil disableAudit
INFO: JpsUtil: isAuditDisabled set to true
Validating WSDL...
   Validating C:\JDeveloper\mywork\HelloWorldApp\Project1\public_html\WEB-INF\wsdl\CountriesService.wsdl
Jan 11, 2017 12:38:22 PM com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.XmlUtil newXPathFactory
WARNING: Factory [com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathFactoryImpl] doesnt support secure xml processing!
Validate WSDL: 0 errors.
Jan 11, 2017 12:38:34 PM oracle.jdevimpl.webservices.tcpmonitor.ServiceTester testService
INFO: Looking for history dockable
Jan 11, 2017 12:38:34 PM oracle.jdevimpl.webservices.tcpmonitor.ServiceTester testService
INFO: Starting AnalayzerInstance
Jan 11, 2017 12:38:35 PM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.server.ServerAdapter <init>
WARNING: Container weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSContainer$BasicContainer@115d551a doesn't support class com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.Module
Jan 11, 2017 12:38:35 PM oracle.jdevimpl.webservices.tcpmonitor.ServiceTester testService
INFO: Showing editor now
Jan 11, 2017 12:41:02 PM Generator handleExceptionImpl
WARNING: Fetching WSDL and mapping files failed for the following reason:
oracle.jdeveloper.webservices.model.GenerationException: Fetching WSDL and mapping files failed for the following reason:
    at oracle.jdeveloper.webservices.model.java.generator.CreateClasses.makeLocalWSDL(CreateClasses.java:604)
    at oracle.jdeveloper.webservices.model.java.generator.CreateClasses.action(CreateClasses.java:184)
    at oracle.jdeveloper.webservices.model.generator.GeneratorAction.run(GeneratorAction.java:142)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper._dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:169)
    at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper.dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1671)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1623)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
    at oracle.bali.ewt.dialog.JEWTDialog.runDialog(JEWTDialog.java:399)
    at oracle.bali.ewt.dialog.JEWTDialog.runDialog(JEWTDialog.java:360)
    at oracle.ide.dialogs.ProgressBar.start(ProgressBar.java:544)
    at oracle.ide.dialogs.ProgressBar.start(ProgressBar.java:395)
    at oracle.ide.dialogs.ProgressBar.start(ProgressBar.java:379)
    at oracle.ide.dialogs.ProgressBar.start(ProgressBar.java:351)
    at oracle.jdeveloper.webservices.model.Model.saveEditSync(Model.java:337)
    at oracle.jdeveloper.webservices.model.Model.saveEditSync(Model.java:245)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.webservices.wizard.jaxrpc.TopDownWizard.runWizard(TopDownWizard.java:672)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.webservices.wizard.jaxrpc.TopDownWizard.runWizard(TopDownWizard.java:222)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.webservices.wizard.jaxrpc.TopDownWizard.invoke(TopDownWizard.java:164)
    at oracle.ide.wizard.WizardManager.invokeWizard(WizardManager.java:430)
    at oracle.ide.wizard.WizardManager$1.run(WizardManager.java:514)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper._dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:169)
    at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper.dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.webservices.tools.weblogic.process.JDevWsdlGetTool.copyBindingFiles(JDevWsdlGetTool.java:292)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.webservices.tools.weblogic.process.JDevWsdlGetTool.copyFiles(JDevWsdlGetTool.java:131)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.webservices.tools.weblogic.WebLogicAdaptor.fetchWsdlExt(WebLogicAdaptor.java:1209)
    at oracle.jdeveloper.webservices.tools.WebServiceTools.fetchWsdlExt(WebServiceTools.java:424)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at oracle.jdeveloper.webservices.tools.WebServiceTools$1.invoke(WebServiceTools.java:141)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy61.fetchWsdlExt(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.jdeveloper.webservices.model.java.generator.CreateClasses.makeLocalWSDL(CreateClasses.java:519)
    ... 54 more
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is the causing error:

Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)

What is does your code say in ArrayList.java on line 653?

HTH, Jim

Comment: thanks for reply. I am not sure what is going on internally calling rangeCheck(), I had simply taken wsdl file and generating Webservices. Can you suggest me how could i debug ??